# spatstat model predictions for a new dataset

Tags: predict, ppm, spatstat

I have a model as below,

```
fit <- ppm(dat.ppp, trend = ~ tpo + sbd + water + nitro + roaden + hpop + temp + elev)
```

I want to predict to a new dataset with same covariate names with different values called newdata as for ppmlasso, rather than getting,

```
predictions = predict(fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

`p <- predict(fit, covariates=mynewdata)`

where `mynewdata` is a named list of images (or functions or windows) containing the new values of the covariates.

See the help for `predict.ppm` in the `spatstat` package.